# Robocopy folder icon changed after run

Tags: batch

I recently found that when using ROBOCOPY command to copy a entire USB content in Win10, the icon of the destination folder always changed to DOCUMENTS' icon and I need to change it back to normal folder's icon manually. Can anyone advise the cause and how to rectify it !
(Even though I created the folder manually in advance before running robocopy command, the icon changed also)

```
robocopy f: %userprofile%\downloads\D114_Backup0915 /mir /a:sh /r:0 /w:0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customized name may be coming from the `Desktop.ini` file. See if there is a file named `Desktop.ini` by opening CMD Prompt in **that** folder and typing this command:

`dir desktop.ini /a`

If it's present, delete it by running:

`del desktop.ini /a`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I should have had excluded copying this .ini file when copying.

Comment: You're welcome. You may either skip desktop.ini files or unset the Read-Only attribute for folders. If the RO attribute is removed, Windows doesn't process desktop.ini for that folder.

Comment: should it be revised like this   robocopy f: %userprofile%\downloads\D114_Backup0915 /mir /a:sh /r:0 /w:0

Comment: should it be revised like this   robocopy f: %userprofile%\downloads\D114_Backup0915 /mir /a-:sh /r:0 /w:0 /xf desktop.ini xjd "system volume information"

Comment: You could try: `robocopy f: %userprofile%\downloads\D114_Backup0915 /mir /a-:sh /r:0 /w:0 /xf desktop.ini /xjd /xd "system volume information"`